# Bot Framework User Identification

Tags: state, botframework, bots

How does bot framework identify the user so it knows to go and grab correct state data? It identifies user correctly when same channel is used, even on different machines. Does it user IP address or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

It is based on the Id property of the user + the channel Id. This user Id depends on the channel: each channel has a specific format of user Id, hence those 2 fields.

Examples:

- Webchat: by default is `userid` but can be changed: `user: { id: 'userid' },`
- Emulator: user ID is always set to `default-user`
- Facebook Messenger: the user ID is a PSID (Page Scoped ID) of the user
- Slack: the user ID is made of the concatenation of several parameters: Slack's Team ID, Slack's channel ID, and Slack's User ID
- SMS: it's the phone number
- Email: it's the email address
- etc

Comment: So if I have a webchat on a kiosk computer then the bot will treat everyone as the same user? If save something to context.UserData then it will be shared for all users unless I delete profile after every conversation?

Comment: Yes, if you haven't changed the user id. You should set the user id to avoid this, you can for example generate a kind of Guid with https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid